# Creating array to insert values into a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

My program currently reads in the values from a text file that is in the .HRM format and will parse them depending on the column the data is contained in and insert the data into the appropriate row. The code I have currently will read in the code and below that i attempted to make the code into a list which is then inserted into the datagridview but I think I have done this incorrectly due to not having the array set up correctly as I am not sure how it would split between the columns nor how I would decide which row of the datagridview the data would be inserted into. This is the code I am using to load in the file:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            string filePath = @"F:\testdata.hrm";
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
                processfile(filePath);
            else
                System.Console.WriteLine("Error - File {0}  not Found", filePath);
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

  //        static void processfile(String filePath)
 //   {
  //      List<string[]> result = File.ReadAllLines("filePath") //read all lines in the file
  //      .SkipWhile(x => x != "[HRData]") //skip lines until reaching the "[HRData]"
   //     .Select(x => x.Split(null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)) //split line by whitespace to get numbers in line
    //    .ToList(); // convert the result to a list
   //     result.ForEach(x => dataGridView1.Rows.Add(x));
          }
    }
}
```

This is the data I am reading in:

```
[HRData]
91  154 70  309 83  6451
91  154 70  309 83  6451
92  160 75  309 87  5687
94  173 80  309 87  5687
96  187 87  309 95  4662
100 190 93  309 123 4407
101 192 97  309 141 4915
103 191 98  309 145 5429
106 190 99  309 157 4662
106 187 98  309 166 4399
107 186 97  309 171 4143
107 185 97  309 170 4914
108 184 96  309 171 5426
108 183 95  309 170 5688
```

So what I will want to do is read each column in the file then adding each column into a seperate array for each of the columns and they will then be inserted into the datagridview in the appropriate columns. I tried to code this but I'm not sure what I did wrong so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"F:\testdata.hrm").Skip(1);
foreach (var line in lines)
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(line.Split(
        new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

**EDIT:**

Based on you comment, you want rotate row to column, and column to row. You can do like bellow:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"F:\testdata.hrm").Skip(1);
List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    list.Add(line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
}
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    List<string> cols = new List<string>();
    for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
    {
        cols.Add(list[j][i]);
    }
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(cols.ToArray());
}
```

To add header to a row:

```
List<string> rowHeaders = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G" };
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = rowHeaders[i];
}
```

Comment: So if I'm reading this right it will add the number that is contained within the column then add it into the datagridview? How would I make it so that it would change the row of the datagridview that it is added to after each blank space that is present?

Comment: Say the first row of the datagridview was time which corresponds to the first column but then I want the second column of data to go under the Health row in the datagridview?

Comment: the Heath row is second or third row?

Comment: Sorry I think I worded that badly I want it to go under the second column of the datagridview not the row.

Comment: Do you mean the first row is `91 91 91...` and the second is `154 154 160...`?

Comment: Oh allow me to explain more clearly what I want hopefully. The first row would be the 91 91 91 etc yes and I would like for them to be inserted into the datagridview in the first column of the datagridview which would be labelled time then the second row of the data would be the 154, 153, 160 etc which I would like to be inserted into the second column of the datagridview and this would hopefully be repeated for each line of the data.

Comment: That is possible. Wait a moment.

Comment: Hey, I tried this and I got an index out of bounds exception is this because I have not inserted the name of the columns that the data is being inserted into?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are implementing Linq into C# code? Also, you want to separate each column into an array of itself, but you have only declared one array? If you want each column into its own array, you need to declare multiple arrays, or you need to declare a 3-D array. I would recommend using a foreach loop that this:

```
foreach(string column in filepath)
{
    string[] result = File.ReadAllLines("filePath");
    string dataColumn = dataGridView1.Rows.Add(result));
}
```